# How can get Python isidentifer() functionality in Python 2.6?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.6, identifier

Python 3 has a string method called [`str.isidentifier`](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/stdtypes.html#str.isidentifier)

How can I get similar functionality in Python 2.6, short of rewriting my own regex, etc.?

Answer (score 15):

the tokenize module defines a regexp called Name

```
import re, tokenize, keyword
re.match(tokenize.Name + '$', somestr) and not keyword.iskeyword(somestr)
```

Comment: For these purposes, you need '^'+tokenize.Name+'$'.

Comment: Add in check for python reserved words, and I like this.

Comment: @Douglas S.J. De Couto - you can use `import keyword`, `keyword.iskeyword(astring)` to check if a string is a keyword, see its documentation [here](http://docs.python.org/library/keyword.html#keyword.iskeyword).

Comment: @JasonR.Coombs, good point. Finally updated this answer :) The `^` is taken care of by using `re.match` rather than `re.search`

Comment: I think this is incorrect; it also triggers on numbers. At least in my implementation of cPython 3.4, token.Name is `'\\w+'`

Comment: @Almar, in Python2 it is `Name = r'[a-zA-Z_]\w*'`. I think in Python3, the OP would use `str.isidentifier`

Comment: @JohnLaRooy ah, you're right. Thanks for pointing that out. Should be carefull to only use this as a fallback on legacy Python then, though.

Answer (score 3):

## Invalid Identifier Validation

---

All of the answers in this thread seem to be repeating a mistake in the validation which allows strings that are not valid identifiers to be matched like ones.

The regex patterns suggested in the other answers are built from `tokenize.Name` which holds the following regex pattern `[a-zA-Z_]\w*` (running python 2.7.15) and the '$' regex anchor.

Please refer to the [official python 3 description of the identifiers and keywords](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#identifiers) (which contains a paragraph that is relevant to python 2 as well).

> Within the ASCII range (U+0001..U+007F), the valid characters for identifiers are the same as in Python 2.x: the uppercase and lowercase letters A through Z, the underscore _ and, except for the first character, the digits 0 through 9.

thus 'foo\n' **should not** be considered as a valid identifier.

While one may argue that this code is functional:

```py
>>>  class Foo():
>>>     pass
>>> f = Foo()
>>> setattr(f, 'foo\n', 'bar')
>>> dir(f)
['__doc__', '__module__', 'foo\n']
>>> print getattr(f, 'foo\n')
bar
```

As the newline character is indeed a valid ASCII character, it is not considered to be a letter. Further more, there is clearly no practical use of an identifer that ends with a newline character

```py
>>> f.foo\n
SyntaxError: unexpected character after line continuation character
```

The `str.isidentifier` function also confirms this is an invalid identifier:

*python3 interpreter:*

```py
>>> print('foo\n'.isidentifier())
False
```

## The `$` anchor vs the `\Z` anchor

---

Quoting the [official python2 Regular Expression syntax](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax):

> `$`
>
> *Matches the end of the string or just before the newline at the end of the string, and in MULTILINE mode also matches before a newline. foo matches both ‘foo’ and ‘foobar’, while the regular expression foo$ matches only ‘foo’. More interestingly, searching for foo.$ in 'foo1\nfoo2\n' matches ‘foo2’ normally, but ‘foo1’ in MULTILINE mode; searching for a single $ in 'foo\n' will find two (empty) matches: one just before the newline, and one at the end of the string.*

This results in a string that ends with a newline to match as a valid identifier:

```py
>>> import tokenize
>>> import re
>>> re.match(tokenize.Name + '$', 'foo\n')
<_sre.SRE_Match at 0x3eac8e0>
>>> print m.group()
'foo'
```

The regex pattern should not use the `$` anchor but instead `\Z` is the anchor that should be used.
Quoting once again:

> `\Z`
>
> *Matches only at the end of the string.*

And now the regex is a valid one:

```py
>>> re.match(tokenize.Name + r'\Z', 'foo\n') is None
True
```

## Dangerous Implications

---

See [Luke's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/577675/7278305) for another example how this kind of weak regex matching could potentially in other circumstances have more dangerous implications.

## Further Reading

---

Python 3 added support for non-ascii identifiers see [PEP-3131](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3131/).

Answer (score 2):

```
re.match(r'[a-z_]\w*$', s, re.I)
```

should do nicely. As far as I know there isn't any built-in method.

Comment: Note that this does not work with unicode symbols, e.g. `'éllo'`

Answer (score 1):

In Python < 3.0 this is quite easy, as you can't have unicode characters in identifiers. That should do the work:

```
import re
import keyword

def isidentifier(s):
    if s in keyword.kwlist:
        return False
    return re.match(r'^[a-z_][a-z0-9_]*$', s, re.I) is not None
```

Comment: Good, but identifiers can start with an underscore.

Comment: Yeah, I was thinking about that when I was writing this.

Answer (score 1):

Good answers so far. I'd write it like this.

```
import keyword
import re

def isidentifier(candidate):
    "Is the candidate string an identifier in Python 2.x"
    is_not_keyword = candidate not in keyword.kwlist
    pattern = re.compile(r'^[a-z_][a-z0-9_]*$', re.I)
    matches_pattern = bool(pattern.match(candidate))
    return is_not_keyword and matches_pattern
```

Comment: Need to allow for capital letters. Above answers have similar problem.

Comment: @Douglas: that's what `re.I` flag is for.

Answer (score 1):

I've decided to take another crack at this, since there have been several good suggestions. I'll try to consolidate them. The following can be saved as a Python module and run directly from the command-line. If run, it tests the function, so is provably correct (at least to the extent that the documentation demonstrates the capability).

```
import keyword
import re
import tokenize

def isidentifier(candidate):
    """
    Is the candidate string an identifier in Python 2.x
    Return true if candidate is an identifier.
    Return false if candidate is a string, but not an identifier.
    Raises TypeError when candidate is not a string.

    >>> isidentifier('foo')
    True

    >>> isidentifier('print')
    False

    >>> isidentifier('Print')
    True

    >>> isidentifier(u'Unicode_type_ok')
    True

    # unicode symbols are not allowed, though.
    >>> isidentifier(u'Unicode_content_\u00a9')
    False

    >>> isidentifier('not')
    False

    >>> isidentifier('re')
    True

    >>> isidentifier(object)
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    ...
    TypeError: expected string or buffer
    """
    # test if candidate is a keyword
    is_not_keyword = candidate not in keyword.kwlist
    # create a pattern based on tokenize.Name
    pattern_text = '^{tokenize.Name}$'.format(**globals())
    # compile the pattern
    pattern = re.compile(pattern_text)
    # test whether the pattern matches
    matches_pattern = bool(pattern.match(candidate))
    # return true only if the candidate is not a keyword and the pattern matches
    return is_not_keyword and matches_pattern

def test():
    import unittest
    import doctest
    suite = unittest.TestSuite()
    suite.addTest(doctest.DocTestSuite())
    runner = unittest.TextTestRunner()
    runner.run(suite)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    test()
```

Answer (score 0):

What I am using:

```
def is_valid_keyword_arg(k):
    """
    Return True if the string k can be used as the name of a valid
    Python keyword argument, otherwise return False.
    """
    # Don't allow python reserved words as arg names
    if k in keyword.kwlist:
        return False
    return re.match('^' + tokenize.Name + '$', k) is not None
```

Comment: `re.match` matches from the beginning of the line.

Answer (score 0):

All solutions proposed so far do not support Unicode or allow a number in the first char *if run on Python 3*.

Edit: the proposed solutions should only be used on Python 2, and on Python3 `isidentifier` should be used. Here is a solution that should work anywhere:

```
re.match(r'^\w+$', name, re.UNICODE) and not name[0].isdigit()
```

Basically, it tests whether something consists of (at least 1) characters (including numbers), and then it checks that the first char is not a number.