# rails 3.2, how to write route for HTTP verb put, and use it in link_to?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, routes

I am trying to write two links for reject& approve actions,
but, I don't know how to write the correct route,

my route.rb

```
put 'approve_class_room/:id(.:format)', :to => 'class_room_member_ships#approve'
put 'reject_class_room/:id(.:format)', :to => 'class_room_member_ships#reject'
```

but, in rake routes, I get:

```
PUT    /approve_class_room/:id(.:format) class_room_member_ships#approve
PUT    /reject_class_room/:id(.:format)  class_room_member_ships#reject
```

so, what would be the correct link_to path ?

my link is

```
= link_to 'approve', approve_class_room_path
```

it wont' work, I get:

```
undefined local variable or method `approve_class_room_path'
```

p.s: I am trying to have the link_to works using AJAX, to do the approve in the same page,
AM I on the right way ? what would be the link_to path ?

Any idea please ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First, to clear the error you need to use [named routes](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#naming-routes):

```
put 'approve_class_room/:id(.:format)', :to => 'class_room_member_ships#approve',
                                        :as => :approve_class_room
put 'reject_class_room/:id(.:format)', :to => 'class_room_member_ships#reject',
                                       :as => :reject_class_room
```

Then, to perform a PUT request, you need to include the `:method` option in your `link_to` call:

```
link_to 'approve', approve_class_room_path, :method => :put
link_to 'reject', reject_class_room_path, :method => :put
```

If you are getting a 404 that results in a GET request instead of a PUT request, it's because the `:method => :put` option relied on JavaScript.  You'll need to make sure [jquery-rails](https://github.com/rails/jquery-ujs) is properly integrated in your app.

Comment: thanks Matt, can you please explain the (.:format) part in the named routes ?

Comment: Since `(.:format)` is in parentheses, it's an optional part of the URL string for the route.  The "." is static, while the ":format" is the actual option.  Rails defaults to format being "html", but this allows you to access `approve_class_room/5.xml`, `approve_class_room/5.json`, etc. assuming you have configured your Rails app to handle those types of formats.  Check out [respond_to](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/MimeResponds/respond_to) and [respond_with](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/MimeResponds/respond_with) if you're interested in handling multiple formats.

Comment: If you're not worried about formats, you can just leave your routes' URL strings as 'approve_class_room/:id' and 'reject_class_room/:id' without the '(.:format)' portion.

Comment: yes, I've removed the format, I just added :constraints => { :id => /\d+/ } to accept only numbers ...

Comment: Not sure, but you may need to change `/\d+/` to `/\A\d+\z/` to match the start and end of the string.  Don't quote me on that.  Otherwise the string "hithere123foo" would pass because it contains numbers, even though the whole string is not numbers.

Comment: oh, I think I need to read more on regular expressions, thanks for the notice

Comment: I've searched for switch \A and switch \z for ruby regular expressions, but couldn't find explanation, can you please explain them ?

Comment: Check out [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5979643/107277) and its accompanying link to [Ruby docs](http://www.ruby-doc.org/docs/ProgrammingRuby/html/language.html#UL).

Answer (score 1):

This may not clear that error, but since the request is a put, you need to specify that in the `link_to`:

```
= link_to 'approve', approve_class_room_path, :method => :put
```

For the route, I think adding this would make the error go away:

```
put 'approve_class_room/:id(.:format)', :to => 'class_room_member_ships#approve', :as => :approve_class_room
```

Comment: thanks, Bill, although your answer is correct, I didn't see the ":as => :approve_class_room" part in the first place, only when I scrolled the scroll bar, I wish I can mark two answers as correct, so here is an up vote :-)