# Regular expression format for modal validations of a text field?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rails-activerecord

I am having a simple title field for a question in the database.

```
validate :title, :presence => true, :format => { :with => regex,
:message => "Invalid Title" }
```

I should make sure that the title of the question doesn't contain only numbers and special characters. It can however contain them along with alphabets. But I should not allow the user to enter only numbers and special characters in the title field.

For example:

```
Will the temperature cross 40 degrees ?
```

Is a valid question.

But,

```
12213232323

?$2112121212

?
```

are invalid question titles.

What would be the format regex for this?

Answer (score 0):

Try this simple one,

```
[a-zA-Z].*\?$
```

This will check the presence of have one or more alphabets in the question. Also check the question is ending with '?'.

Answer (score 0):

I would go with something like this `/\A.*[a-zA-Z].*\z/` - this will let you have alphabets in any position.

p.s. don't use ^ and $ for determining start and end of an input string. Here is the explanation [Difference between \A \z and ^ $ in Ruby regular expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/577653/difference-between-a-z-and-in-ruby-on-rails-regular-expressions)