# php second if validation is not working

Tags: php, mysql

### php second if validation is not working

second if that is : $firstnameErr = "Only letters and white space allowed ";  is not working directly it redirect to success.php.

### help me friends

```
<?php
    $firstname="";
    $firstnameErr="";
    
    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']== "POST") {
       $valid = true;
         
     if(empty($_POST["fname"]))
    {
        $firstnameErr="*firstname is Required";
        $valid=false;   
    }
    else
    {
    $firstname=test_input($POST["fname"]);
     if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$firstname))
           {
           $firstnameErr = "Only letters and white space allowed"; 
           }    
    } 
       
     //if valid then redirect
      if($valid){
          include 'database.php';
          echo '<META HTTP-EQUIV="Refresh" Content="0; URL=success.php">';    
        exit;
    //   header('Location: datasubmitted.php');
    //   exit();
      }  
    
    }
    
    function test_input($data)
    {
         $data = trim($data);
         $data = stripslashes($data);
         $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
         return $data;
    }
    
    ?>
```

Comment: What is the input you're passing that recreates this error? Please insert $valid=false; into line 19

Comment: `$_POST["fname"]`, not `$POST["fname"]`

Comment: You might want to consider using A z rather than ^ $ - see the accepted answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/577653/difference-between-a-z-and-in-ruby-regular-expressions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When firstname has extra characters other than letters & white spaces you need to set $valid to false. Otherwise it would redirect to success irrespective of what characters it contains.

```
       $firstname=test_input($_POST["fname"]); //<-- changed this line. you have missed "_"
       if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$firstname))
       {
          $firstnameErr = "Only letters and white space allowed"; 
          $valid = false; //<-- Add this line
       }
```