# The provided regular expression is using multiline anchors (^ or $)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, regex, ruby-on-rails-4

I trying to write a Image validation format that makes sure url ends with either .png, .jpg or .gif .

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base

  mount_uploader :image_url

  validates :title, :presence => true,
            :uniqueness => true
  validates :image_url, :presence => true,
                        :format => {
                           :with => %r{\.(gif|jpg|png)$}i,
                           :message => 'must be a URL for GIF, JPG or PNG image.'
                        }
end
```

But when i start my server. seeing this:

**The provided regular expression is using multiline anchors (^ or $), which may present a security risk. Did you mean to use \A and \z, or forgot to add the :multiline => true option?**

Comment: What's the question? Consider doing what it says.

Comment: Just replace `$` with `\z`, looks like it's the same in your case anyway.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

`^` and `$` are both line anchors.  If a user were to pass in a string with `http://www.foo.com/bar.png\nfoo_bar_baz!`, then your regex is going say that the input is valid because it will match `.png` to the newline, which is not what you want.

Change your regex above to be `%r{\.(gif|jpg|png)\z}i` instead.  The `\z` is an end of string anchor, which is what you want instead of the end of line anchor.

There are some great answers on another, very similar question: [Difference between \A \z and ^ $ in Ruby regular expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/577653/difference-between-a-z-and-in-ruby-regular-expressions).