# Regular Expression for excluding numbers or special characters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex, forms

I'm setting up a user form in Rails that requires a first name and last name. I decided to use the 3rd to last regular expression from the this [Ruby doc](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveModel/Validations/ClassMethods/validates_format_of) to ensure that they don't enter any numbers or special characters. Unfortunately when I return to the form I get this error:

> The provided regular expression is using multiline anchors (^ or $),
>   which may present a security risk. Did you mean to use \A and \z, or
>   forgot to add the :multiline => true option?.

I'm just beginning to learn RegEx so if there's a better way to write this validation I'm all ears.

**Code:**

```
validates :first_name, :last_name, length: {minimum: 2}, format: {with: /^([^\d\W]|[-])*$/, message: 'First Name/Last Name cannot have any numbers or special characters'}
```

Comment: The warning is quite explicit. It tells you that you're using anchors for start and end of line on a multiline regex without saying it will work on singleline where the `\A` is prefered over `^` and `\z` is preferred over `$` in single line check.  so with a regex of the form `/\A([^\d\W]|[-])*\z/` it would work, you may test this at http://regex101.com which give you explanation on the anchors/parts of regex.

Comment: See http://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html#regular-expressions for an explanation

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The documentation you linked to states:

> Note: use \A and \Z to match the start and end of the string, ^ and $ match the start/end of a line.

Since you don't need multiline support for names (i.e. newlines in the name should be regarded invalid), you can safely change this to:

```
/\A([^\d\W]|[-])*\Z/
```

See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24920413/473467) which explains the security risk a bit more.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to use `\A` for start of line and `\z` for end of line instead of `^` and `$` due to security reasons. So your regexp should be

```
/\A([^\d\W]|[-])*\z/
```