# validation not to allow special character but allow space and numbers in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, regex

I have tried this

```
validates :name, format: { with:  /^[a-zA-Z0-9 ]*$/ }
```

but its giving error `regular expression is using multiline anchors (^ or $)`

Please guide me how to solve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
validates :name, format: { with:  /\A[a-zA-Z0-9 ]+\z/ }
```

hope this will help you.

Comment: for more details go through this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24919330/the-provided-regular-expression-is-using-multiline-anchors-or