# Regular Expression of only spaces, letters, and numbers no special characters

Tags: ruby, regex, validation

I am trying to make a regular expression that validates letters, numbers and spaces ONLY. I dont want any special characters accepted (i.e. # )(*&^%$@!,)

I have been trying several things but nothing has given me letters(uppercase & lowercase), numbers, and spaces.

So it should accept something like this...

```
John Stevens 12

james stevens

willcall12
```

or

```
12cell space
```

but not this

```
12cell space!

John@Stevens

james 12 Fall#
```

I have tried the following

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$

[\w _]+

^[\w_ ]+$
```

but they allow special characters or dont allow spaces. This is for a ruby validation.

Comment: You should take several minutes to learn [how to format code](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting). It helps to make your question look more clear.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You almost got it right. You could use this:

`/\A[a-z0-9\s]+\Z/i`

`\s` matches whitespace characters including tab. You could use  (space) within square brackets if you need exact match for space.

`/i` at the end means match is not case sensitive.

Take a look at [Rubular](http://rubular.com/) for testing your regexes.

**EDIT**: As pointed out by [Jesus Castello](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1333436/jesus-castello), for some scenarios one should use `\A` and `\Z` instead of `^` and `$` to denote string boundaries. See [Difference between \A \Z and ^ $ in Ruby regular expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/577653/difference-between-a-z-and-in-ruby-regular-expressions) for the explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a working example that will print matching results:

```
VALIDATION = /\A[a-zA-Z0-9 ]+\Z/

words = ["willcall12", "John Stevens 12", "12cell space!", "John@Stevens"]

words.each do |word|
  m = word.match(VALIDATION)
  puts m[0] if m 
end
```

I can recommend [this article](http://www.blackbytes.info/2015/06/mastering-ruby-regex/) if you would like to learn more about regular expressions.

Comment: When I try this and input "name " (name with a space) it come back invalid.

Comment: It seems to work for me if I just add "name " to the words array. How exactly are you using the regex in your code?

Comment: I want it to validate a word even if it has a space at the end or if it has a space then number, etc.