# URL , Scanner & Delimiter : How does this Java Line of Code Works?

Tags: java, url, java.util.scanner, delimiter

Can anyone help me  understand how does this line of code works:

```
String s = new Scanner(new URL("http://example.com").openStream(), "UTF-8").useDelimiter("\\A").next();
```

The code is used to directly read from the webpage.
How exactly is the scanner object converted to a string and why we use delimiter.

Thanks.

Comment: It is not "converted". The `next()` Method returns a `String`. Have a look into the JavaDoc of Scanner. [useDelimiter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#useDelimiter(java.lang.String)) is also described there.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Here is what happens, with abuse of  indentations

```
     new Scanner(                           // A new scanner is created
             new URL("http://example.com")  // the scanner takes a Stream 
                                            // which is obtained from a URL
          .openStream(),                    // - openStream returns the stream
       "UTF-8")                             // Now the scanner can parse the        
                                            // stream character by character
                                            // with UTF-8 encoding

     .useDelimiter("\\A")                   // Now the scanner set as 
                                            // delimiter the [Regexp for \A][1]
                                            // \A stands for :start of a string!

   .next();                                 // Here it returns the first(next) 
                                            // token that is before another
                                            // start of string. 
                                            // Which, I'm not sure 
                                            // what it will be
```

[From the Java documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html)

> A simple text scanner which can parse primitive types and strings using regular expressions.
>   A Scanner breaks its input into tokens using a delimiter pattern, which by default matches whitespace. The resulting tokens may then be converted into values of different types using the various next methods.

So you just replaced `\A` as delimiter (instead of  whitespace).
BUT `\A` [has a specific meaning when evaluating as regular expression!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/577653/difference-between-a-z-and-in-ruby-regular-expressions)

If your stream contains only the following text

\Ahello world!\A Goodbye!\A

Your code will return the **entire line** `\Ahello world!\A Goodbye!\A`

If you wanted to strip on the sequence of a backslash followed by a upper case A, then you should use `\\\\A`.

Thanks to @Faux Pas to point out that!

Answer (score 3):

Adding to Kuzeko's answer, \A matches the beginning of the entire text. So, I don't think his 'hello world' example is valid.

Comment: you mean that it will return the empty string as first?

Answer (score 2):

Scanner is not "converted". On the freshly created instance, `useDelimiter` is called, which returns a Scanner instance with the delimiter property set accordingly, then on that instance `next` is called which returns a `String`.

You may want to lookup Scanner in Java Doc for further reading:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html