# String comparison like "abcDEF" == "*DEF"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am working on an rails app in which I need a comparison like:

```
url == "http://localhost:3000/admin/admin_login"
```

I am wondering that is there a way to compare like:

```
url == "*/admin/admin_login"
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a regexp.

```
irb(main):001:0> url = "http://localhost:3000/admin/admin_login"
=> "http://localhost:3000/admin/admin_login"
irb(main):002:0> url =~ /admin\/admin_login\z/
=> 22
irb(main):003:0> url =~ /foo\/something_else\z/
=> nil
irb(main):004:0> "http://localhost:3000/admin/admin_login/bar" =~ /admin\/admin_login\z/
=> nil
```

Comment: I try and encourage people to use `x.match(y)` instead of `x =~ y` since the former is more clear. Also worth noting that `\z` is preferable to `$` for reasons [explained in this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/577653/difference-between-a-z-and-in-ruby-regular-expressions).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion to use `\z`! I've updated the answer accordingly. As for `x =~ y` vs. `x.match(y)`, I can't say I find one more clear than the other, so I'll just keep it as is.

Answer (score 5):

You can use [`String#include?`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html#method-i-include-3F):

```
url = "http://localhost:3000/admin/admin_login"
url.include?("/admin/admin_login")
=> true
```

Other way is use [`String#end_with?`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html#method-i-end_with-3F):

```
url.end_with?("/admin/admin_login")
=> true
```

This works if you want to check if url ends with this argument.

Comment: Note that this does not work as the wildcard `*/admin/admin_login` would: `"http://localhost:3000/admin/admin_login/foo".include?("/admin/admin_login")` gives you `true`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use include? or []

value="http://localhost:3000/admin/admin_login"

```
value["/admin/admin_login"]
 => "/admin/admin_login" 
value["/admin/admin_login1"]
 => nil 
value[/\/admin\/admin_login/]
 => "/admin/admin_login" 
value.include?("/admin/admin_login")
 => true
```

Comment: when a value is nil then .include? will throw an error. How could i know value return strings and i can check with .include? method...