# How to write Regex to not allow this phone number with newline character?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, regex, rspec, rspec-rails

I have problem to write regex to pass last test with phone number value equal "+48 999 888 777\naseasd". Here are my files. What I'm doing wrong?

app/models/user.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
  :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  validates :phone_number, format: { with: /[+]?\d{2}(\s|-)\d{3}(\s|-)\d{3}(\s|-)\d{3}/, allow_nil: true }

end
```

spec/models/user_spec.rb

```
require 'rails_helper'

describe User do

  it { is_expected.to allow_value('+48 999 888 777').for(:phone_number) }
  it { is_expected.to allow_value('48 999-888-777').for(:phone_number) }
  it { is_expected.to allow_value('48 999-888-777').for(:phone_number) }
  it { is_expected.not_to allow_value('+48 aaa bbb ccc').for(:phone_number) }
  it { is_expected.not_to allow_value('aaa +48 aaa bbb ccc').for(:phone_number) }
  it { is_expected.not_to allow_value("+48 999 888 777\naseasd").for(:phone_number) }

end
```

Error in console is:

```
Failures:

1) User should not allow phone_number to be set to "+48 999 888 777\naseasd"
 Failure/Error: it { is_expected.not_to allow_value("+48 999 888 777\naseasd").for(:phone_number) }
   Expected errors  when phone_number is set to "+48 999 888 777\naseasd", got errors: ["can't be blank (attribute: \"email\", value: \"\")", "can't be blank (attribute: \"password\", value: nil)"]
 # ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:9:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

Comment: Add `\A` at the beginning and `\z` at the end of the pattern.

Comment: Thanks! It's working now. Here I found more information about it: [Difference between \A \z and ^ $ in Ruby regular expressions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/577653/difference-between-a-z-and-in-ruby-regular-expressions). I was using earlier ^ $.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your

```
it { is_expected.not_to allow_value("+48 999 888 777\naseasd").for(:phone_number) }
```

means you want your pattern to only match the entire string.

Add `\A` at the beginning and `\z` at the end of the pattern.

Note that `^` matches at the start of a line in Ruby (while `$` matches at the end of the line), and in RoR usually cause an exception. The `\z` anchor is better than `\Z` for validation purposes since `\Z` can match before the final newline in the string and `\z` only matches at the very end of the string.