# [[:punct:]] matches differently in irb and rails test

Tags: ruby, regex, unit-testing, ruby-on-rails-4

[[:punct:]] doesn't match any punctuation when it's called by a rails model test. Using the following code

```
test "punctuation matched by [[:punct:]]" do
  punct_match = /\A[[:punct:]]+\Z/.match('[\]\[!"#$%&\'()*+,./:;<=>?@\^_`{|}~-]')

  puts punct_match
  puts punct_match.class
end
```

this outputs a non-printable character and NilClass.

However, if I execute the same statement

```
punct_match = /\A[[:punct:]]+\Z/.match('[\]\[!"#$%&\'()*+,./:;<=>?@\^_`{|}~-]')
```

in irb matches correctly and outputs

```
[\]\[!"#$%&'()*+,./:;<=>?@\^_`{|}~-]
=> nil
```

What am I missing?

Ruby version => 2.2.4,
Rails version => 4.2.6

Comment: What *exactly* are you entering in irb?

Comment: input: punct_match = /\A[[:punct:]]+\Z/.match('[\]\[!"#$%&\'()*+,./:;<=>?@\^_`{|}~-]')
output: #<MatchData "[\\]\\[!\"\#$%&'()*+,./:;<=>?@\\^_`{|}~-]">

Comment: Using MRI v2.2.4? I tried this, and got no match. Cannot reproduce.

Comment: Ahhhh hang on a minute. You're using Ruby `2.4` not `2.2`, aren't you? The behaviour of this regex did change. Your rails vs pry environments are in different ruby versions.

Comment: woow! Isn't rails a gem? it should be use the same ruby as you know ruby.

Comment: Yes, `rails` is a gem (which contains a bundle of smaller gems such as `active_record`, `active_support`, `active_model`, ...). But it's perfectly possible to have multiple versions of ruby installed (e.g. using `rvm` or `rbenv`). You must have configured `pry` to run as a `2.4.x` gem.

Answer (score 2):

The behaviour of `/[[:punct:]]/` changed slightly in ruby version `2.4.0`.

[This bug](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/12577) was raised in the ruby issues, which links back to [this (much older)](https://github.com/k-takata/Onigmo/issues/42) issue in Onigmo - the regexp engine used since Ruby `2.0+`.

The short answer is, these characters were not matched by `/[[:punct:]]/` in ruby versions `<2.4.0`, and are now matched:

```
$+<=>^`|~
```

You must be running `irb` in a newer ruby version than this rails application, which is why it matches there.

---

On a separate note, you should alter your code slightly to:

```
/\A[[:punct:]]+\z/.match('[]!"#$%&\'()*+,./:;<=>?@^_`{|}~-]')
```

- Use `\z`, not `\Z`. There is a [slight difference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5979643/1954610): `\Z` will also match a new line at the end of the string.
- You have unnecessary back-slashes in the string, such as `'\^'`
- You have repeated a `[` character: `'[\]\['`