# PHP username check with no spaces and text

Tags: php, text

How can you tell if a string has only a username and not any other text (e.g. `"@username"` OR `"@username "`   RATHER THAN `"@username text"`)

Comment: Personally, for usernames I'd use a regular expression that limits user input to only certain allowed characters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a regular expression that looks for `@[A-Za-z]+`

That'll just match letters... if you need to allow numbers and underscores, you'll need something like `@[A-Za-z0-9_]+`.

To allow zero or more trailing whitespace characters you can add `\s*`

Wrap in `^` and `$` to match the start and end of the string.

Here's the whole regex:

`@[A-Za-z0-9_]+\s*`

If you need more matchable characters you can add them into the brackets. You may need to escape dash (-) as `\-` depending where you put it.

If you need just A-Za-z0-9_ then you can shortcut that as \w if you like. Here's the short version:

`@\w+\s*`

Aside: if you are here from ruby for some reason - be careful with ^ and $ - you should "probably" be using \A and \z instead (see [Difference between \A \z and ^ $ in Ruby regular expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/577653/difference-between-a-z-and-in-ruby-regular-expressions) )

Comment: How would you use this in PHP? Can you give an example?

Comment: @ThomasGeorge You can use `if (preg_match('/^@\w+\s*$/', $username) === 1) {/* username is correct */} else {/* username is incorrect */}`