# Ruby regex to allow A-Za-z0-9

Tags: regex, ruby

I have the following regex:

```
/([A-Za-z0-9]+)([A-Za-z0-9\-\_]+)([A-Za-z0-9]+)/
```

It is not working according to my needs, which are:

- do not allow spaces
- allow capital English letters
- allow lowercased English letters
- allow digits
- the string may not contain both a hyphen and an underscore
- *hyphen*: hyphen cannot be at the beginning or at the end of the string; 
  There can be any amount of hyphens but consecutively there can be only 1 hyphen (`a--b` is invalid).
- *underscores*: underscore cannot be at the beginning or at the end of the string; There can be any amount of underscores but consecutively there can be only 1 underscore (`a__b` is invalid)
- the string must contain at least 1 character (letter)

Valid examples:

- `a1_b_2_hello`
- `2b-ffg-er2`
- `abs`
- `123a`

Invalid examples:

- `_a1_b_2_hello`
- `2b-ffg_er2-`
- `__`
- `--`
- `a__`
- `b--2`

Comment: you say `the string must contain at least 1 character`, so how is `123` valid? is `a` or `1` supposed to be valid?

Comment: @depperm it's a mistake in description, good catch, `123` is invalid

Comment: @depperm I post my commend in wrong post, I want ask Andrey Deineko what he try to match, Andrey Deineko give an example what you try match

Comment: You have a greatly formalized algorithm and are trying to solve it with a regular expression. May I ask why? What would be wrong with checking all conditions step be step?

Comment: @CarySwoveland I edited the question as you suggested, thanks

Comment: @AlekseiMatiushkin I thought of implementing a step by step check using Ruby (Rails) and the method occurred cumbersome and I thought that probably string validation is better with regexp, because is regexp not what it is there for?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could add the a-zA-Z in a character class, and in the repetition of 0+ times match either a hyphen or an underscore `[-_]` followed by 1+ times what is listed in the character class `[A-Za-z0-9]+`.

Use a capturing group with a [backreference](https://www.regular-expressions.info/backref.html) to get a consistent using of `-` or `_`

```
\A[A-Za-z0-9]*[A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9]*(?:([-_])[A-Za-z0-9]+(?:\1[A-Za-z0-9]+)*)?\z
```

About the pattern

- `\A` Start of string
- `[A-Za-z0-9]*[A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9]*` Match at least 1 a-zA-Z
- `(?:` Non capturing group

  - `([-_])` Capturing group 1, match either `-` or `_`
  - `[A-Za-z0-9]+` Match 1+ times what is listed
  - `(?:`

    - `\1[A-Za-z0-9]+` Backreference `\1` to what is captured in group 1 to get consistent delimiters (to prevent matching `a-b_c`) and match 1+ times what is listed
  - `)*`Close non capturing group and make it optional
- `)?` Close non capturing group and make it optional
- `\z` End of string

[Regex demo](https://rubular.com/r/xO9uV5rPyu3Dv7)

See [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/577653/difference-between-a-z-and-in-ruby-regular-expressions) for a detailed explanation about the anchors.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! this one matches `a-b_c` https://regex101.com/r/aY5Doc/2/ which shouldn't

Comment: Editing the description, sorry

Comment: It works, thank you very much. I have 0 understanding and there's 0 sense to even try...

Comment: I will add an explanation.

Comment: @AndreyDeineko I have added an explanation about the pattern.

Comment: This regex passes all the tests in my answer.

Comment: @Thefourthbird do you by chance know how to now convert this regexp into one supported by Postgres? I'd like to add it as a check constraint

Comment: @AndreyDeineko You could use [regexp_matches](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/functions-matching.html). It will return the value of the capturing group when it is present. In this case to keep the backreference you could wrap the whole pattern in another group, which will then be group 1 and use a backreference to the inner group 2. `^([A-Za-z0-9]*[A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9]*(?:([-_])[A-Za-z0-9]+(?:\2[A-Za-z0-9]+)*)?$)')` [Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/J3BXWe/1) and a [postgress demo](https://rextester.com/DPYHP26741).

Comment: @AndreyDeineko In the test it appears to be valid right? https://rextester.com/EBZY48543 Which version of postgresql do you use?

Comment: @Thefourthbird `PostgreSQL 10.6` I don't understand it, in the psql console the string is valid (matching returns true), but when added as check constraint this one becomes invalid...

Comment: @Thefourthbird please nevermind. I don't know why but after resetting the db the check works properly - I needed to escape the back slash: `CHECK (name ~ '^([A-Za-z0-9]*[A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9]*(?:([-_])[A-Za-z0-9]+(?:\\2[A-Za-z0-9]+)*)?$)');`

Comment: Does it work when you write out both alternatives with `-` or `_`. [Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/MZjSkQ/1) and [Postgresql demo](https://rextester.com/KNLZL11457)

Comment: @AndreyDeineko No problem at all, glad it works. Good luck!

Answer (score 4):

I find it convenient to put all the special conditions at the beginning in positive and negative lookaheads and follow these (which consume no characters) with the general requirement, here `[a-z\d_-]+\z`.

```
r = /
    \A           # match start of string  
    (?!.*        # begin negative lookahead and match >= 0 characters
      (?:--|__)  # match -- or __ in a non-capture group
    )            # end negative lookahead
    (?![-_])     # do not match - or _ at the beginning of the string
    (?!.*[-_]\z) # do not match - or _ at the end of the string
    (?!          # begin negative lookahead
      .*-.*_     # match - followed by _ 
      |          # or
      .*_.*-     # match _ followed by - 
    )            # end negative lookahead
    (?=.*[a-z])  # match at least one letter 
    [a-z\d_-]+   # match one or more English letters, digits, _ or -
    \z           # match end of string
    /ix          # case indifference and free-spacing modes
```

```
 "a".match? r          #=> true   
 "aB32-41".match? r    #=> true
 "".match? r           #=> false (must match a letter)
 "123-4_5".match? r    #=> false (must match a letter)
 "-aB32-4_1".match? r  #=> false (cannot begin with -)
 "aB32-4_1-".match? r  #=> false (cannot end with -)
 "_aB32-4_1".match? r  #=> false (cannot begin with _)
 "aB32-4_1_".match? r  #=> false (cannot end with _)
 "aB32--4_1".match? r  #=> false (cannot contain --)
 "aB32-4__1".match? r  #=> false (cannot contain __)
 "aB32-4_1".match? r   #=> false (cannot contain both - and _)
 "123-4_5$".match?  r  #=> false ($ is not a permitted character)
```

This regular expression is conventionally written:

```
/\A(?!.*(?:--|__))(?![-_])(?!.*[-_]\z)(?!.*-.*_|.*_.*-)(?=.*[a-z])[a-z\d_-]+\z/i
```

Comment: your answers are always an absolute joy to read, thank you Cary!

Answer (score 1):

You could add `(?!.*(\-\-|__|_.*\-|\-.*_).*)`, to check for consecutive dash or underscores and only one type before the middle capture group, and `(?=.*[a-z].*)` before everything to check for at least one character. So the whole thing would look like:

```
(?=.*[a-zA-Z].*)([A-Za-z0-9]+)(?!.*(\-\-|__|_.*\-|\-.*_).*)([A-Za-z0-9\-\_]+)([A-Za-z0-9]+)
```

Comment: Give an example what you try match.

Comment: It works as well as the @Thefourhtbird's answer. Thank you very much

Comment: This passes all the tests in my answer except the first, when the string is `"a"`. I expect it's an easy fix. Note `(?=.*[a-z].*)` needs to include capital letters and can be simplified to `(?=.*[a-zA-Z])`.

Comment: @CarySwoveland the OP doesn't mention length, idk if a single character is valid

Answer (score 0):

#### Solution using lookahead/lookbehind assertions

```
^[a-z\d](?!.*--.*)(?!.*__.*)(?!.*-.*_)(?!.*_.*-)[\w-]*(?<=[^_-])$
```

[Click here to see demo](https://rubular.com/r/0Ur7evNvdWOAKy)

- `^[a-z\d]` - Start with any letter or digit
- `(?!.*--.*)(?!.*__.*)` - Lookahead to make sure there's no `__` or --

  - `(?!.*-.*_)(?!.*_.*-)` - Lookahead to make sure there's no `_` followed by `-` or vice-versa
- `[\w-]*` - optionally match any letter, digit, `_` or a `-`
- `(?<=[^_-])` - Lookback to make sure it doesn't end with a - or `_`

Sample data:

```
# Start with a letter
a
ab
abc
abc123
abc123abc

# Has underscores
a_b
a_b_c

# Has dashes
a-b
a-b-c

# Can't start or end with an underscore or dash
_abc
abc_
abc-
-abc

# Can't contain -- or __
a__
a__b
a__b__c
d--
d--e
a--b--c

# Can only use _ or - but not both

a-_b
a-_b-_c
a-_b_-d
a-_b_____f--_-_--__
```

Comment: If you test your regex against the examples in my answer you will find that `"a"`, `"123-4_5"`, `"aB32--4_1"`, `"aB32-4__1"`, `"aB32-4_1"` and `"123-4_5$"` yield incorrect results.

Comment: Ahhh I wasn't sure what was meant by

  if `_` and `-` are excluding - string can't have both.

So you can only have _ or - -- got it

Comment: I made the same mistake.