# How to get rid of TypeError

Tags: ruby

I have my class

```
class A
  def to_s
    'string'
  end
  def inspect
    'string'
  end
end
```

and trying to do something like this

```
a = A.new
'somestring' + a
```

Error is "in `+': can't convert A into String (TypeError)"

Is there any way to fix it?

P.S. using 'somestring' + a.to_s isn't an option.

**Answer found. to_str method needed.**

Comment: You should post your answer as an actual answer and then accept it, so this question shows up as answered in the questions list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`#to_s` is for *representing* an object as a `String`. In your case, you need to *convert* the object to a `String`, because `String#+` only deals with `String`s. In Ruby, type conversions are done with the three letter form of the `to_X` methods, i.e. `to_int`, `to_ary`, `to_hash` (someone can't count to three ...), `to_str` and so on.

So, you need to implement `to_str`, in order to make that work.

*However*, you should *only* implement `to_str`, if your object actually *is* a string! If it's something else, you *must not* implement `to_str` and rather have the clients explicitly represent it as a string using `to_s`.

Basically, implementing `to_str` in Ruby is like inheriting from `String` in Java: it means that `A` IS-A `String`.

As an example, look at which classes in the Ruby core library *actually* implement the type conversion methods:

- the only class that implements `to_ary`, is `Array` itself,
- the only class that implements `to_hash`, is `Hash` itself and
- the only class that implements `to_str`, is `String` itself.

This should show you that implementing `to_str` is a *very* serious matter that should not be undertaken lightly.

The only conversion method that does not have only a trivial no-op implementation, is `to_int`, which is also implemented by `Float` and `Numeric`. And actually, I think that is a mistake, since there is an infinite number of `Float`s which aren't `Integer`s. And `Numeric` is a *superclass* of `Integer`, so saying that every `Numeric` IS-A `Integer` is even more strange.

Comment: Symbol also implements (or implemented) `to_int`. Can't work out if that's a no-op or not. If you're doing `Integer(:yikes)`, that may be [undesired behavior](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/49274/safe-integer-parsing-in-ruby/2551994#2551994)!