# How to force/check user to input desired date-type

Tags: ruby, user-input

How do I write code to fore a user to enter a certain value type such as an int, and then force or loop a prompt until a user enters an int, rather than a string or numbers with string characters? I am thinking some type of Boolean with for or while loop.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please show what you have tried, what doesn't work with your approach (e.g. error messages, what exactly doesn't work, ...) and what you tried to fix the issue. Please edit your question with the additional information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's start with some basics. Put this into a file `userinput.rb`:

```
print "Please enter a number: "
input = gets
puts input
```

Then run with `ruby userinput.rb`. You get a prompt and the program outputs whatever you type in.

You want your input to be an integer, so let's use `Integer()` to convert the input:

```
print "Please enter a number: "
input = gets
puts Integer(input)
```

Type in an integer and you'll get an integer output. Type in anything else and you'll get something like this:

```
userinput.rb:3:in `Integer': invalid value for Integer(): "asdf\n" (ArgumentError)
        from userinput.rb:3:in `<main>'
```

Now you can build a loop that prompts the user until an integer is typed in:

```
input = nil # initialize the variable so you can invoke methods on it
until input.is_a?(Fixnum) do
  print "Please enter a number: "
  input = Integer(gets) rescue nil
end
```

The interesting part is `input = Integer(gets) rescue nil` which converts the integer and, in case of an `ArgumentError` like above, the error gets rescued and the `input` var is nil again.

A more verbose way of writing this (except that this catches only `ArgumentError` exceptions) would be:

```
input = nil # initialize the variable so you can invoke methods on it
until input.is_a?(Fixnum) do
  print "Please enter a number: "
  begin
    input = Integer(gets)
  rescue ArgumentError # calling Integer with a string argument raises this
    input = nil        # explicitly reset input so the loop is re-entered
  end
end
```

Some notes:

1. Please don't get confused by [`Integer`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Integer.html) and [`Fixnum`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Fixnum.html). `Integer` is the parent class that also encapsulates big numbers, but it's fairly standard to test for `Fixnum` (as in the loop head). You could also just use `.is_a?(Integer)` without changing the behavior.
2. Most Ruby tutorials probably use `puts` over `print`, the latter's output doesn't end with a newline, which makes the prompt appear in one line.

Comment: Thanks very much, helpful. I don't really understand the code as far as fixnum up till the rescue nil, is there a place you would recommend I could read up to better grasp the until loop and fixnum. Also, You can use the gets method inside the integer class?

Comment: `gets` is just a method that always returns a string. If you enter `asdf`, it will call `Integer("asdf")`, If you enter a number like `23`, it will call `Integer("23")`. The `Integer()` part is not a class but a function. I'm well aware this must be confusing, I'd advise you to run `irb` and play around in that prompt to get the concept. See also this on SO: http://stackoverflow.com/a/49282/473467

Comment: I'd also recommend to read up on loops in Ruby, a Google search will get you further here. I've edited my answer to give a more verbose example.

Comment: I see. And so essentially you are using the gets method inside of the integer method.So what exactly does that make 'Fixnum' is that a class then? I'm having trouble understanding the structure of ruby language. Do you have skype? Please add me or username: jarggsx