# Validate a String on an Integer's input, Ruby

Tags: ruby, string, validation, integer

I'm practicing a little with Ruby and I want to handle the age's input, for example if someone types "eleven" instead of 11, I want to show a message that, the person know he/she can't use a String.

Here's my code

```
saludo = "Hola ¿Como te llamas?"

puts saludo
STDOUT.flush
#STDOUT es una constante global que almacena las salidas del programa. flush vacía cualquier dato almacenado, y por lo tanto, limpiará cualquier resultado anterior.
nombre = gets
STDOUT.flush
puts "Entonces te llamas #{nombre}"

puts "¿Cuantos años tienes?"
edad = Integer(gets.chomp)
#gets.chomp elimina el /n de gets
#El .to_i pasa el String a Integer
if edad > 0
  if edad >= 18
    puts "Eres mayor de edad, puedes votar y esas cosas"
  else
    puts "Tienes que moverte con el permiso de tus padres."
  end
else
  puts "prueba"
end
```

Comment: The user cannot type in anything other than a string.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: I wanted to validate the user's age in a way that he/she only write numbers, for example user says "eleven" instead of 11. That would be an error.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49274/safe-integer-parsing-in-ruby

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using `gets` and you expect to receive a number, parsing this to integer, then you can "skip" the `chomp`, this way using `gets.to_i`, you can convert the input from the user in an integer, and you can see that everything that's not a number is converted to `0`, so you can check if `edad` after the operation is 0 `edad.zero?`, and this way to show your message:

```
puts '¿Cuantos años tienes?'
edad = gets.to_i
if edad.zero?
  puts 'Debes ingresar un número'
end
```

You can initialize `edad` as 0, and then using `until` to create a loop, which asks the user to enter a number, so, when `edad` takes a non-zero value the code outs from the `until` loop, and you can pass the next step:

```
edad = 0
until !edad.zero?
  puts '¿Cuantos años tienes?'
  edad = gets.to_i
  if edad.zero?
    puts 'Debes ingresar un número'
  end
end
puts edad
```

Comment: This is the easiest way, Thank you very much!

Comment: "you can see that everything that's not a number is converted to 0". This is incorrect. `"0".to_i #=> 0`

Answer (score 2):

I've always just done it this way. Adding a method to the `String` class to do the check with makes things a lot easier.

```
class String
  def is_i?
    !!Integer(self)
    rescue ArgumentError, TypeError
      false
  end
end

puts "1".is_i?
puts "asda".is_i?
```

Some people may not like it, because it uses exceptions, but I think it's fine.

Comment: `self == self.to_i.to_s` is probably less messy.

Comment: That's true. It really depends on what's acceptable.

Comment: The method I made will (should) accept anything that is a valid Integer literal, which I think is ideal. I'm not sure if there's really another straight forward way to do this. Regular expressions are also a valid approach though (actually, probably better), but meh, good enough.

Comment: Normally I'd lean towards a regular expression, but how many digits are allowed? 10? 100? A billion? Ruby's bignum system will attempt to accommodate nearly anything. Try `Integer('9' * 1e6)` for example.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to check the datatype of the input, you can use something like this:

```
input = gets.chomp
input.class == Fixnum
```

Since, every input in ruby is taken as a string, you can convert the input to integer using `to_i` like:

```
input = gets.to_i
```

Check if the input value is 0 which is the default value taken by the strings converted to integer as below:

```
if input == 0
puts("Please enter an integer")
```

Comment: Isn't what I wrote?

Comment: I just saw that you had not mentioned about the FixedNum part. And for the sake of completeness, I added the next check. Not copying your answer :)

Comment: Ah, I see, sorry!

Answer (score 0):

When you do `Integer(gets.chomp)` if `gets.chomp` is not an strictly integer string (i.e. 1, 2, -12, etc), it will raise an error

So you can do this:

```
input_string = gets.chomp
edad = nil
begin
  edad = Integer(input_string)
rescue 
  puts "#{input_string} is not an integer"
end
# edad will still be nil if there was a problem
```

Answer (score 0):

input = gets.chomp

```
if input != "0" && input.to_i == 0
    puts "Invalid age format. Integer expected"
else
    age = input.to_i
end
```

Answer (score 0):

#### A more Ruby way

Use a [**case-expression**](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/doc/syntax/control_expressions_rdoc.html#label-case+Expression) which allows you to compare your input with string-ranges thus negating the need to use `String#to_i`:

```
#age.rb
loop do
  puts 'Enter age'
  case gets.chomp
  when /\D/
    puts 'Digits only, try again', '======================'
  when '0'..'17'
    puts 'too young'
    break
  when '18'..'120'
    puts 'old enough'
    break
  else
    puts 'Invalid age, try again', '======================'
  end
end
```

Using [`Kernel#loop`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Kernel.html#method-i-loop) ensures you continue asking the user for an input until they enter a valid age. Valid ages are defined in the case-expression as `0 - 120`. If a valid age is entered the loop is broken with `break`.

---

#### Running the code

```cl
$ ruby age.rb
Enter age
eleven
#Digits only, try again
#======================
Enter age
10000
#Invalid age, try again
#======================
Enter age
5
#too young

$ ruby vote.rb
Enter age
35
#old enough
```